# Delete parent rows based on previously deleted child rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have tables A, B, and C. Table A is a parent table of B and C. Now, in my batch file, it has this delete statement where it deletes records from Table B and C:

```
DELETE b.*, c.*
FROM tableB AS b
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c
   ON c.tableB_id = b.id
WHERE c.date IS NULL
AND DATE(c.updated_at) != CURDATE()
```

What I wanted to do is delete all records from table A where id (table A's primary key) is equal to the those that have been deleted from the `DELETE` statement above.

Furthermore, both tables B and C have a column (say, tableA_id) which is a foreign key to table A. I tried the following queries but I don't think this is the right thing to do because they're not basing from the previous `DELETE` statement above:

```
DELETE a FROM tableA a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.tableA_id FROM tableB b
)

DELETE a FROM tableA a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT c.tableA_id FROM tableC c
)
```

Thoughts?

Edit: I have the same problem with this one but it's based on oracle: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49634/delete-rows-in-parent-table-based-on-criteria-in-child-table-oracle

Comment: Your requirement is a bit off perhaps.  Are you saying that if I delete a single child record from `B` or `C` that the entire `A` should be deleted?  That might cause a key constraint error if there are other (non deleted) children still referencing `A`.  It seems like you would want `ON DELETE CASCADE` here, but again that doesn't make sense to cascade delete from children to parents.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete tables with foreign keys first before you can delete the original record they reference. But you can write a script that will gather the ids of records in table A from tables B and C. Delete the records in B and C and then loop through the list of ids to remove them from table A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create foreign key index with cascade delete option to delete records in other tables.

In your case, create the foreign key index in B and C with A having cascade delete option.So when you delete a record in A, corresponding key values will be deleted in other tables as well.

Refer
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/